# Why does the following FFT result in a different set of frequencies than that used for generation?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft, sox

I generate the an audio file `SingleTone.wav` using the following `sox` command.

```
sox -n SingleTone.wav synth 10 sin 525
```

I then execute the following program to perform an fft on a sample of this tone.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, rfft
from scipy.io import wavfile
from sys import argv

# FFT sample count
N = 8192

# Sampling frequency
samples_per_second = 44100

# Frequency resolution
freq_resolution = samples_per_second / N

fs, data = wavfile.read(argv[1])
a = data.T
b=[(ele/2**8.)*2-1 for ele in a]
c = fft(b, N)
d = len(c)/2 - 1 
frequencies = [x*freq_resolution for x in xrange(d)]
print '\n'.join(",".join([str(f),str(x)]) for f, x in zip(frequencies, abs(c[:d])))
plt.plot(frequencies, abs(c[:d]),'r')
plt.show()
```

The output I get is a frequency spike between 440 Hz and 455 Hz, rather than at `525 Hz` as I had expected.

What is the reason for the disparity?

Valid answers would point at a misunderstanding of FFT, a bug in the code, or anything incorrect about the setup.

Comment: `N = 8192` Do you actually have this many samples? It seems you design your frequency axis based on hard-coded numbers rather than the information in the file.  Use `len(data)` and `fs` instead!

Comment: Doesn't sox generate 48 kHz sample rate by default? Try adding `rate 44100` to your sox command

Comment: @mtrw, Yes it looks like that fixed it for the most part!

Comment: It looks like I am also getting a spike at 0 Hz in addition to one at 525 for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: The peak at 0 Hz is the DC component. It is likely that the data has a DC component so that all sample values are positive, and stored as unsigned integers. You can't hear the DC component, so it is irrelevant.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Yup, it looks like subtracting the mean removes that peak. Thanks!

Comment: See answer below, there are a couple of issues, retrieving the sampling rate from the wave file and using the library to manage the frequency list for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  use the sampling rate from the wav file, and, for convenience and fewer bugs, use the frequency list provided by fft library.

Here is the code per the above,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, rfft, fftfreq, rfftfreq
from scipy.io import wavfile
from sys import argv

samples_per_second, data = wavfile.read(argv[1])

# FFT sample count
N = 8192

a = data.T
b=[(ele/2**8.)*2-1 for ele in a]

c = fft(b, N)
d = len(c)/2 - 1 

frequencies = fftfreq(N,1./samples_per_second)

#print '\n'.join(",".join([str(f),str(x)]) for f, x in zip(frequencies[:d], abs(c[:d])))

plt.plot(frequencies[:d], abs(c[:d]),'r')
plt.show()
```